# Copy and paste with clipboard exception in Swing

Tags: java, swing

I try to copy a string to clipboard:

```
public class A {
private static final String LINE_BREAK = "\n";
private static final String CELL_BREAK = "\t";
StringSelection selection;
private Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
private StringBuffer strBuffer = new StringBuffer();
public final Action copyAll = new 
AbstractAction(ResourceBundleManager.getString(ResourceBundleManager.COPY_ALL)) {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     strBuffer .append(LINE_BREAK);
                    selection = new StringSelection(strBuffer .toString());
                    clipboard.setContents(selection, selection);
    }};}
```

So it will not copy all the strings and i have an exception in the terminal:

```
ERROR: Uncaught exception in thread 'AWT-EventQueue-0': cannot open system clipboard
java.lang.IllegalStateException: cannot open system clipboard
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.windows.WClipboard.openClipboard(Native Method)
```

Comment: Are you constructing every instance of `A` in the AWT event dispatch thread?

Comment: I'm constructing an instance(once) of A to use it in the AWT event dispatch thread